# Creating a custom transformer in scikit-learn that adds cluster labels

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am writing a custom transformer in scikit-learn that adds cluster labels as a new column using stock KMeans to pandas dataframe.
The custom transformer should fit to existing data then transform the unseen data by adding the a new column with the index name 'Cluster' and return a new dataframe with the additional column without modifying the original dataframe.
Below is the code that that I came up with:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

class AddClustersFeature(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, clusters = 10): 
        self.clusters = clusters
        self.model = KMeans(n_clusters = self.clusters)
           
    def fit(self, X):
        self.X=X
        self.model.fit (self.X)
        return self.model
       
    def transform(self, X):
        self.X=X
        X_=X.copy() # avoiding modification of the original df
        
        X_['Clusters'] = self.model.transform(self.X_).labels_
        
        return X_

cluster_enc_tr_data = AddClustersFeature().fit_transform(enc_tr_data)
cluster_enc_tr_data
```

Unfortunately the code does work properly. The result is a dataframe with cluster numbers as column indices, with row numbers and unknown previously values.
Any help or tips will greatly be appreciated.

**Update 23 of June 21 v2:**
Please see below the code after implementing Ben's revised comments.
It works perfectly now.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

class AddClustersFeature(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, clusters = 10): 
        self.clusters = clusters
        
           
    def fit(self, X):
        self.X=X
        self.model = KMeans(n_clusters = self.clusters)
        self.model.fit (self.X)
        return self
       
    def transform(self, X):
        self.X=X
        X_=X.copy() # avoiding modification of the original df
        X_['Clusters'] = self.model.predict(X_)
        return X_

cluster_enc_tr_data = AddClustersFeature().fit_transform(enc_tr_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fit` method must always return `self`.

The problem here is that `fit_transform(X, y)`, inherited from `TransformerMixin`, is just `fit(X, y).transform(X)`; your `fit` now returns the underlying `KMeans` transformer, and *that* is used to transform `X` instead of *your* `transform`.

A few more notes though:

1. `KMeans.transform` gives the cluster-distance matrix, but you want the cluster labels.  Use `predict` instead.  And drop `labels_`, so just `X_['Clusters'] = self.model.predict(X_)`.)
2. `__init__` should only set attributes that appear in its signature, in order for cloning to work (required for e.g. hyperparameter searches).  You can define `self.model` at `fit` time.
3. in `transform`, you use `self.X_` but it is never defined; I guess you mean just `X_`.  There no real reason to save `X` at fit time either; `self.X` is never really needed?
4. This will only work on dataframes; that may not be a problem for you, but keep it in mind.  (You can't use this as a step in a pipeline after builtin `sklearn` transformers, because those will return numpy arrays.)

Comment: Thanks Ben for your answer. I am not sure if I am clear what you meant please bear in mind I am quite new to custom transformers. Please see the the code in question edit above after implementing your comments. Unfortunately it still does not work properly.
By the way I also graduated from University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign.

Comment: I have tried to add a cluster feature with this custom transformer before a regressor in a pipeline but that did not improve the cv scores. Do you Ben or anyone elso think it could work or would this result in an overfitted model and that is why the cv scores have not improved?

Comment: That's a better question for stats.SE or datascience.SE, but I imagine it's very data-dependent.  The clusters are of course obtained from your other independent variables, so in that sense you're building in redundancy; a high-capacity model could probably build that information itself and wouldn't benefit much, whereas a low-capacity model might benefit from the cluster transformation.  For next steps, I'd have a look at how good the clusterization is independently.  Are you one-hot encoding the cluster labels?  What regressor?

Comment: I am creating a stacking ensemble for the Ames Housing dataset. I am evaluating several regressors SVR, ridge, kernel ridge, linear regression, xgboost ,catboost and HuberRegressor. After clustering the standarized dataset with some additional features created  and one hot encoding the cluster labels there were some improvements to the cv scores but not breathtaking.